# Functioning Time vs Lifetime of Light bulb

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Lifetime of a light bulb follows exponential distribution with $x$ means hours. If $n$ bulbs were switched on at same time and after $t$ time only $n-m$ were found to be functioning. Remaining $m$ bulbs had lifetime $x_{i}$ for $i=1$ to $m$. What will be the PDF of the bulbs that are still functioning?

My confusion is, since these  $n-m$ bulbs are still functioning how can we find their PDF?

Comment: Presumably the individual lightbulbs at the start have identical and independent distributions.  It may be worth remembering that exponential distributions have the memorylessness property

Comment: The question doesn't make sense - if "only $n-m$ were found to be functioning," why would there be a "remaining $m$ bulbs?"